# PowerShell filtering range of file names

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a very simple (as far as I know :-) ) script in PowerShell v2.0.

Every morning I need to look at some files to check if they are up to date.
All of the files are in the same folder.

The files are named like so: from1.rar, from2.rar from13.rar, from14.rar, from27.rar, from29.rar and so on. As you can see, the files are in different ranges. I want to filter the name of the files by a range that I determine. I suppose regex will do the trick, but I don't know how to use it...

What I have for now is just filtering and sorting all of the files by time and name into one table:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter "*.rar" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | sort name | Format-Table LastwriteTime, name > C:\Users\user1\Desktop\update.txt
```

Now I want to break the table to form a number of groups (or smaller tables) from the names of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$low  = 10
$high = 25
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.rar' | ? {
  $_.Name -match 'from(\d+)\.rar' -and
  [int]$matches[1] -gt $low -and
  [int]$matches[1] -le $high
} | ...
```

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $files = 'from1.rar','from13.rar','from14.rar','from27.rar','from29.rar'
PS C:\> $files
from1.rar
from13.rar
from14.rar
from27.rar
from29.rar
PS C:\> $files | ? {
>>   $_ -match 'from(\d+)\.rar' -and
>>   [int]$matches[1] -gt $low -and
>>   [int]$matches[1] -le $high
>> }
>>
from13.rar
from14.rar
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, though i still need to have a table with the files sorted by date and name.

Comment: @alon: You're supposed to replace the ellipsis (`...`) at the end of the code snippet with your further processing steps. The demonstration is just for displaying how the filter works.

Comment: ok. I can use "do until" loop and set a range for each group. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To break your tables into groups of tables, just add the `-GroupBy` parameter to the cmdlet [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx).

For example, to create a table for each file by its property `Name`:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter "*.rar" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | sort name | Format-Table LastwriteTime, name -GroupBy Name
```

But that might generate too many groups if you have many files, so you may group the table on the first letter of the `Name` property, like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter "*.rar" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | sort name | Format-Table LastwriteTime, name -GroupBy @{name="First Letter";E={ ($_.name).substring(0,1) }}
```

Or, to group the table on the first two letters of the `Name` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter "*.rar" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | sort name | Format-Table LastwriteTime, name -GroupBy @{name="First Letter";E={ ($_.name).substring(0,2) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to use a regex:

```
$range = 5..10

get-childitem From*.rar | 
where {$range -contains ($_.name -replace 'From(\d+)\.rar','$1')}
```